# How to measure number and rate of users, who performed ANY of conversions from set?

Tags: google-analytics

I have 2 conversion events, let's say A and B.
How do I find number of users, who performed any of them. It means A, B, (A & B) all counts as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information from a [segment](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en). Add a new segment and use the Conditions tab of the segment builder to create it. You can create an OR condition for your two conversion events, so that anyone who converts on at least one of them will count.

[image: Screenshot of building the segment]

I have set the segment to filter Users instead of Sessions, but for your purpose it doesn't actually matter which one you use. The important part is below that line, where you will originally see a single line where you can set a condition for a dimension or metric. Click the OR button at the right-hand end to get a second line. I have set them to be number of conversions greater than 0 for each of 2 goals; you could also set them to be event hits or pageviews if your conversions are not formally Goals in analytics.

Once you have filled this out, off to the right-hand side of the segment builder it will tell you how many users are in the segment (during the time period you're currently set to), which is the number you are asking for.